# How to create virtual folders using php?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-5.4

I am using php with aws elasticbeanstalk. 
I want to create folder that accept this url :

```
www.example.com/481818
```

where 481818 present an id that is changed.

so i want to create file that accept every request form this structure `www.example.com/integer`. and fetch the id.

i don't know how to create this file.

I can do it with this url : `www.example.com/?id=4545454` . but I don't want this url structure.

thank you

Comment: See also [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in you `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

It should do what you want, I didn't use elastic-beanstalk before, hopes I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to rewrite all non-existent URLs to a script. On Apache you can make it adding these rules to `.htaccess` file in your www root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```